# How to update Hyper-V integration features in Fedora VM?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, virtual-machine, fedora, hyper-v

I have a virtual machine running Fedora 24 within Hyper-V on my Windows 8.1 physical machine. The summary panel on the machine says that my integration services need upgraded, but I cannot find a way to do that.
[image: Fedora Virtual Machine Summary]

All of my online searches reveal that Hyper-V integration services are already integrated into the Linux kernel, which is certainly true, but they clearly need upgraded. I have tried downloading the integration services files from Microsoft and running them, but I receive an error message saying

> Unsupported Linux Distribution

Is there a way I can actually upgrade my integration services?

Comment: Got any solutions..?